# Using a Loop to replace a single phrase with different phrases from a list

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop, sed, replace

Working in the shell I would like to take all instances of "replace_me" in my text file (table), and replace it with values in another file (markers), working incrementally down the list.

i.e. the first instance of "replace_me" in table would get replaced by "replaced_1" from markers, the second by "replaced_2" until the list was exhausted.

Looking around other answers I think it would have to be something like a nested loop (for, and then if), along these lines but I'm not sure how to make it actually work, and move incrementally down the 'markers' list.

```
#!/bin/bash
fileReplace='markers'
fileChange='table'
linesreplace=`cat $fileReplace`
lineschange=`cat $fileChange`

for line in $lineschange ; do

if $linechange = "replace_me"
sed "s/{$lineschange}/{$linesreplace}/g" 
else   
done
```

I'm sure this is basic so pointers in the right direction, or examples are very welcome.

Comment: is `replace_me` a whole line? Would you be interested in a solution in ViM?

Comment: why do you separate the search and replacements strings? one file would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Indentation is your (and our) friend.

Comment: @Shahbaz, thank you it's not a whole line.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, thank you  I will try next time. I have to admit I don't fully understand the indenting conventions.

Answer (score 2):

Save the next script into file, e.g. `do_replace.sh`

```
replace_me="replace_me"
while read replace_to
do
    sed -i "" "1,/$replace_me/s/$replace_me/$replace_to/" $1
done
```

and run it with:

```
sh do_replace.sh file_where_need_replace.txt < file_with_replacements
```

e.g. from the file_where_need_replace

```
aaa aaa aaa
replace_me bbb bbb
ccc ccc ccc
ddd replace_me ddd
eee eee eee
fff fff replace_me
```

with the following replacements:

```
111
222
333
```

will produce:

```
aaa aaa aaa
111 bbb bbb
ccc ccc ccc
ddd 222 ddd
eee eee eee
fff fff 333
```

or simple perl:

```
perl -ple 'BEGIN{@x=qx(cat replacements.txt);chomp @x}s/replace_me/shift(@x)/e' < where_to_replace.txt
```

Comment: thank you. I tried the first exampel using my data then files made with the examples you've provided tbut there is an error message:
"sed: can't read 1,/replace_me/s/replace_me/111/: No such file or directory." I will try the second example now.

Comment: are you sure that you don't  forgot "quotes"?

Comment: yes the quotes are the same as in you example for do_replace.sh

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you know the number of replaceme stuffs, the solution should be like this:

```
for i in {1..5}; do
 linesreplace= `head -${i} runjavareplicate.sh | tail -1`
 sed -i "s/${linechange}/${linesreplace}/" filename
done
```

Comment: If you ever find yourself doing `head | tail` in a loop, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it sounds like it's reasonable to assume the files have the same number of lines. Hopefully the comments adequately explain what's going on here:

```
#!/bin/bash

fileReplace='markers'
fileChange='table'
IFS=$'\n' # 'Internal Field Separator' affects how bash splits words (i.e. for arrays).
linesreplace=( $(<"$fileReplace") ) # Create a bash array from the lines of each file
lineschange=( $(<"$fileChange") ) 

for ((i=0; i<"${#linesreplace[@]}"; i++)); do # iterate numerically over the lines
    line="${lineschange[i]}"
    case "$line" in
        replace_me)
            printf '%s\n' "${linesreplace[i]}" # Print out the replaced line
        *)
            printf '%s\n' "$line" # Print out the original line
    esac
done
```

Comment: yes the files have the same lines. I have found a solution above but I will later on try this because you have kindly taken the time to annotate everything beautifully I am sure to learn something! Will feedback later thank you.